# mule 3.7 gmail connector config-with-oauth issues

Tags: oauth, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to create gmail integration using the new gmail connector using config-with-oauth. I added appropriate dependencies in pom.xml, still it is failing to find the mule-gmail xsd.

mule config xml >[mule xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hshira/f03f4291b583817a3f5a/raw/32babc18bbc6de465ee68aa15e94d2c6874b929c/gistfile1.txt)

Pom > [pom.xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hshira/78423ffd6747ffcce740/raw/023f005bb76ab38c4132d27afa8eb3c955e6f738/gistfile1.txt)

This is the > [error](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hshira/9937b5fae9ef0b9850d1/raw/34bc4d0706faf0aa0c00f96865426b672020e7de/gistfile1.txt)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the connector as an inclusion on the mule maven plugin
:

```
<inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.module</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-gmail</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
```

And then you also need to add the oauth-callback-config

```
<gmail:config-with-oauth name="GMail_Connector"
        consumerKey="xxx" consumerSecret="xxx" doc:name="GMail Connector">
        <gmail:oauth-callback-config></gmail:oauth-callback-config>
    </gmail:config-with-oauth>
```